# Where is the earliest place to sleep?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want my character to sleep ASAP from the start of the game. Where is the earliest place I can do that? Let's say it's in Riverwood. Is there or is it possible for a borrowable bed to spawn, like at a campsite, earlier than reaching Riverwood?

Comment: If you're just after a stat bonus there's the 3 standing stones available. Alternatively you could attempt to kill Anise at her cabin, but the chances of doing that so early in the game are tiny.

Comment: Maybe I'm just bad at Skyrim, but why is having the well rested bonus right away important?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 places you can sleep before reaching Riverwood.

- A bed inside the Embershard mine (as stated by Rodrigo Guedes)
- A hunters camp at the first 3 ritual stones/standing stones.

Both will give you the "Rested" state.
Note that the beds inside the mine will require you to kill 3 bandits before being able to reach it.

Screenshots for locations:

**The First Standing Stones**
[image]

**The Hunters Camp From The Stones**
[image]

**The Bed Providing The Rested State**
[image]

**The Camp Site Inside The Embershard Mine**
[image]

Comment: Kid Thor shows the way, literally with screenshots.

Comment: @NiteCyper its a female (sorcerer) actually :p

Answer (score 22):

If you want the "well rested" status, the earliest place is the inn in Riverwood. If you don't, there is a place to sleep in the mine before you reach Riverwood.

Comment: If you go to Riverwood with Ralof, you can stay in Hod and Gerdur's house. Can you not get a well-rested bonus there?

Comment: That will only give you the Rested bonus.  Well Rested requires either an owned bed or a rented bed.

Answer (score 12):

when you first enter the keep at helgen there is a bed, if you side with imperial the bed(s) are in front of you, if you side with stormcloaks, then after you kill the imperials you can go through the gate to the same room with the beds.

Comment: These beds are uninteractable. I checked.

Comment: Indeed, cannot use the beds

Comment: That sucks, i never thought to check before i just assumed they would work.